# How to compose a graphQL query from a REST Api response?

Tags: reactjs, rest, graphql, apollo

I have an API response from a REST API server which I called using my REACT + Apollo with apollo-link-rest. but the response of the API looks like this

```
[
 [
   {
    "name": "joe"
    "address": "123 street hello city"
   },
   {
    "name": "joe2"
    "address": "1233 street2 hello2 city"
   }
 ],
 2356
]
```

How can I create a query with this kind of response that has an array with a number as a last item in the array and the first item of the array consist of list of users?

So far I just have this query.

```
const QueryTest = gql`
  query people {
    people @rest(type: "People", path: "/allpersons")
  }
`;
```

Comment: Based on tags seems like you are using `Apollo`, in that case Data Sources are way to go https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/data-sources/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st: you need `name` and `address` props within (inside) `people` query - 'ask for what you need' - to get results.

2nd: Work with `apollo-link-rest` usually needs [type patching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest#options.typePatcher) - technique used to adapt/transform existing (REST) responses to the current needs (structures). It can be combined with [response transformer](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest#options.responseTransformer) but this step isn't required.

Sometimes you need to add `id` (calculated from other fields, unique) for nested types (apollo normalizing cache requirement) or define additional 'response type' above desired/required type - google for type patching examples (f.e. `patchDeeper` usage) or tutorials... define patchers, use debugger...

It's far easier when you know what to expect/what is needed - compare responses with working graphql responses.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, you can use `responseTransformer` in your link to transform the response.

```js
const restLink = new RestLink({
    uri: '...',
    responseTransformer: async response =>
        response.json()
              .then((data: any) => {
                if (Array.isArray(data)) return { data }
                else return data
            })
});
```

So you should be able to use the query like this:

```
const QueryTest = gql`
  query people {
    people @rest(type: "People", path: "/allpersons") {
      data
    }
  }
`;
```

Where `data` would contain:

```json
[
 [
   {
    "name": "joe"
    "address": "123 street hello city"
   },
   {
    "name": "joe2"
    "address": "1233 street2 hello2 city"
   }
 ],
 2356
]
```